# Identify 2 points $(x,y)$ at which the curve is not smooth (Parametric Equation)

Tags: calculus, parametric

Original parametric equations:

$x(t) = 7t - 7 \sin(t)$

$y(t) = 7 - 7 \cos(t)$

1st derivatives:

$x'(t) = 7 - 7 \cos(t)$

$y'(t) = 7 \sin(t)$

I've come to the conclusion that the curve is not smooth when $t = 2k\pi$ ($x$-intercepts). I'm just not entirely sure why though. My best guess for why $t = 2k\pi$ is because as $t$ increases toward $2\pi$, the McDonalds like arches on the graph drop toward $y = 0$ very rigidly/sharply, rather than smooth.

To me my assumption seems a little to literal, but I can't really come up with any other reasons when I analyze the formal criteria of a smooth curve where "a curve is called smooth when f' and g' are continuous on an interval (I) and not simultaneously 0, **except possibly at the endpoints of interval (I).**"

Considering that $t = 2\pi$ is a full rotation of the unit circle, I would assume that the x-intercept at $t = 2k\pi$ can technically be an endpoint of an interval, although $\cos/\sin$ are indefinitely continuous otherwise. Any thoughts/solutions are appreciated!

Comment: This is a cycloid. You can google for it, it is a well-known curve.

Comment: I've cross referenced multiple videos via Youtube as well as the solutions to relatively identical problems that only differ by leading coefficients via Slader & Chegg.. I'm fairly certain that the value t = 2kπ will allow me to correctly indicate the sequential points of the curve that aren't smooth. I'm just having a hard time rationalizing the logic. I've found all the above references to be a bit vague when it comes to the reasoning for the ultimate solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If we have $y=f(t)$ and $x=g(t)$ then:
$$\frac {dy}{dt}=f'(t)$$ and
$$\frac {dx}{dt}=g'(t)$$
Hence we have-
$$\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {f'(t)}{g'(t)}$$
Now note that a function is said to be differentiable if it's left hand and right hand derivatives are equal, hence to compare it is necessary that they be finite. You will see that-
$$\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {\sin t}{1-\cos t}=\cot(\frac t2)$$
This means that at $t=2k\pi$, we have the derivative tending towards $\infty$. Hence the sharp change.

Also, it might be interesting to consider, that the curve you've traced out here is called a cycloid, and this would be the locus traced by a point on a disc of diameter $7$ units which is pure rolling on the ground(which you can consider the $x$-axis).

Comment: Thank you for reminding me to mention that the curve is a cycloid. I did solve for dy/dx and found that dy/dx = 0 when t = 0, π, 2π, 2kπ... As I mentioned before I wouldn't necessarily consider cos/sin to be finite due to the lack of asymptotes, but relative to the unit circle, t = 2π is a full revolution and on the graph of the original set of parametric equations there happens to be a x-intercept(s) at t=2kπ. I've found an identical problem on slader that only differs by coefficients and the solution says the curve isn't smooth at (4kπ,0). Although I'd argue that (2kπ,0) is more appropriate.

Comment: At $2k\pi$ derivative tends to $\infty$, hence function isn't differentiable

Comment: I'm a bit confused. At 2kπ derivative tends to ∞ in what way? In the sense that the parametric equations are continuous? At t = 2kπ both the original parametric equations as well as dy/dx = 0. Wouldn't that be considered a finite number rather than ∞? To clarify, when t = 2π in particular is applied to the original parametric equations the resulting point is (14π,0). So in that regard I mean the original parametric equations  = 0 as an x-intercept. Dy/dx on the other hand truly = 0 at t = 2kπ.

Comment: If by f'(t) you mean f'(t) = 7 -7cos(t)... Wouldn't f'(2kπ) = 7 - 7(1) = 0? Likewise if g'(t) = 7sin(t), wouldn't g'(2kπ) = 7(0) = 0 as well? Forgive me for my lack of intuition, my spring semester ends this Friday and naturally I'm a bit mentally exhausted. I appreciate your patience.

Comment: Indeed, but if you consider the limiting value, that tends to $\infty$. I have edited the answer for your benefit. Please read it now.

Comment: Very true! That's essentially what I was thinking, but considering the limiting value is much more precise. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of this discussion, a curve is "smooth" at a point $x$ if $f'(x)$ exists. $f'(x)$ can alternatively be written as $\frac{dy}{dx}$, and we know that
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$$
Therefore, for this problem, we find the values of $t$ at which $\frac{dy}{dx}$ DNE. That occurs precisely when $\frac{dx}{dt}=0$ but $\frac{dy}{dt} \neq 0$. Those values of $t$, as you discovered, are at $t = 2\pi k$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What an interesting insight regarding dx/dt = 0 but  dy/dt ≠ 0. That makes the definition my textbook provides much more clear.